# Google Maps slow in Android 2.2's WebView when using CSS3 transformations

Tags: android, google-maps, css, android-webview, flicker

I can't get CSS3 transformations and Google Maps to play nice together in Android 2.2's WebView. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ejipaq/1/edit), with two buttons to test transformations. You will need to enable "Emulate touch events" in Chrome to be able to click on them in the desktop. The device I'm using has a 1024x600 screen.

If I don't do anything special, there is flickering when a transformation starts. Now, if I add -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden to the element I'm applying the transformation to, everything is silky smooth and there is no flicker, but the map becomes impossibly slow, and you can't barely scroll around.

I tried to work around this by removing -webkit-backface-visibility by setting it to visible. This works, and the map will be fine again, but setting the property causes flicker. I also played around with -webkit-perspective and -webkit-transform-style, which also seem to get rid of the flicker when a transformation starts, but they also cause flicker when removed.

I also noticed that applying '-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden' to any element on the page makes the flickering at the beginning of transformations disappear. So I put a small div with the property on it, and when the transforms were done, I hid it with "display: none". This causes flicker as well.

My question is, thus: how can I have -webkit-backface-visibility (which I need in order to make the transformations flicker-free) and Google Maps, without making Maps slow?

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues can be 2.2 is rather out of date and you should realistically be using 3.0 now to support tablets. Also, if you are testing on an emulator then this will be your issue.